# How to show an alert box output and inside the function also have the calculation

Tags: javascript, html

I want when the user click button Submit Order, the alert box contain words and also total price of the selected size and topping appear , then have a button ok so it will close the alert button.I need to use JavaScript to calculate the total price of the pizza if the user select the radio button and checkbox. But I don't really know how to do it. Can anyone help me . Btw for this problem I only use JavaScript and html only

This is some codes that I've already progress on using html and javascript

```html
<form>
<p><b>Step 2 : Select the size of pizza you want:</b></p>
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="small" id="radOne">Small
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium" id="radTwo">Medium
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="large" id="radThree">Large
        <br>

        <p><b>Step 3 : Select the pizza toppings you want:</b></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="peperoni">Pepperoni
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Sausage">Sausage
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Pineapple">Pineapple
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Black Olives">Black Olives
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Meatball">Meatball <br>

        <br>    
        <input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="Submit Order">
        <input type="button" onclick="reset()"  value="Clear Entries">
   </form>
```

```
<script>
    function submit() {
        document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
        var radOne = document.getElementById("radOne");
        var radTwo = document.getElementById("radTwo");
        var radThree = document.getElementById("radThree");
        var price;

        if (radOne.checked){
            price = 15.00;}
        else if (radTwo.checked){
            price = 20.00;}
        else
            price = 25.00;
        {alert("MY PIZZA CAFE");}

    }

    function reset() {
    document.getElementById("frm1").reset();
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the correct path, it's just that submit() function triggers the form submit which does a redirect. Check the code below for sausage and pepperoni and do the same for the other checkboxes.

```js
function calculate(e) {
  var radOne = document.getElementById("radOne");
  var radTwo = document.getElementById("radTwo");
  var radThree = document.getElementById("radThree");
  var pepperoni = document.getElementById("pepperoni");
  var sausage = document.getElementById("sausage");
  var price;

  if (radOne.checked) {
    price = 15.00;
    alert("Small checked");
  }
  if (radTwo.checked) {
    price = 20.00;
    alert("Medium checked");
  }
  if (radThree.checked) {
    price = 25.00;
  }

  if (pepperoni.checked) {
    alert("Pepperoni checked");
    price += 1.5;
  }
  if (sausage.checked) {
    alert("Sausage checked");
    price += 2;
  }

  if (confirm("Your Pizza is " + "Total Price is " + price)) {
    alert("Ok");
  } else {
    alert("Cancelled");
  }
}

function reset(e) {
  document.getElementById("frm1").reset();
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <p><b>Step 2 : Select the size of pizza you want:</b></p>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="small" id="radOne">Small
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium" id="radTwo">Medium
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="large" id="radThree">Large
    <br>

    <p><b>Step 3 : Select the pizza toppings you want:</b></p>
    <input id="pepperoni" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="peperoni">Pepperoni
    <input id="sausage" type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Sausage">Sausage
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Pineapple">Pineapple
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Black Olives">Black Olives
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Meatball">Meatball <br>

    <br>

    <input type="button" onclick="calculate(this)" value="Submit" />
    <input type="button" onclick="reset(this)" value="Clear Entries" />
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot . this code also works :) it helps my assignment a lot . Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

Somebody has answered your question. But here is my solution. You can refer to it.
Hope to help, my friend :))

https://jsfiddle.net/ga7ptu5o/

```
<form id="frm1">
<p><b>Step 2 : Select the size of pizza you want:</b></p>
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="small" id="radOne">Small
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium" id="radTwo">Medium
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="large" id="radThree">Large
        <br>

        <p><b>Step 3 : Select the pizza toppings you want:</b></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="peperoni">Pepperoni
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Sausage">Sausage
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Pineapple">Pineapple
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Black Olives">Black Olives
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Meatball">Meatball <br>

        <br>    
        <input type="button" onclick="submitFunc()" value="Submit Order">
        <input type="button" onclick="reset()"  value="Clear Entries">      
   </form>

function submitFunc(){
        //document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
        var form = document.getElementById('frm1');        
        var price = 0;
        var size_value; 

        var checked_size = document.querySelector('input[name = "size"]:checked');
        var checked_topping = form.querySelectorAll('input[type = "checkbox"]');

        if(checked_size != null){  
            size_value = checked_size.value;
            if(size_value === 'small'){
                price = 15.00;
            }else if (size_value === 'medium'){
                price = 20.00;
            }else{
                price = 25.00;
            }
        } else {
            alert('You have to select a Pizza size'); 
            return;
        }

        var txt_topping = "";
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < checked_topping.length; i++){
            if(checked_topping[i].checked){
                 txt_topping = txt_topping + checked_topping[i].value + ", ";
            }
        }

        if(txt_topping != '')
            txt_topping = '. With ' + txt_topping + ' topping';

        alert('You have selected ' + size_value + ' size, price is: ' + price + txt_topping);
    };

    function reset() {
        document.getElementById("frm1").reset();
    };
```

Comment: thank you . it helps a lot i've change some of the code but this helps a lot thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form>
<p><b>Step 2 : Select the size of pizza you want:</b></p>
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="small" id="radOne">Small
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium" id="radTwo">Medium
        <input type="radio" name="size" value="large" id="radThree">Large
        <br>

        <p><b>Step 3 : Select the pizza toppings you want:</b></p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="peperoni">Pepperoni
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Sausage">Sausage
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Pineapple">Pineapple
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Black Olives">Black Olives
        <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="Meatball">Meatball <br>

        <br>    
        <input type="button" onclick="submitFX()" value="Submit Order">
        <input type="button" onclick="reset()"  value="Clear Entries">
   </form>
<script>
    function submitFX() {
     //   document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
        var radOne = document.getElementById("radOne");
        var radTwo = document.getElementById("radTwo");
        var radThree = document.getElementById("radThree");
        var price;

        if (radOne.checked){
            price = 15.00;}
        else if (radTwo.checked){
            price = 20.00;}
        else{
            price = 25.00;
            }
        alert("MY PIZZA CAFE \nTotal Price is : "+ price +"");

    }

    function reset() {
    document.getElementById("frm1").reset();
    }

    </script>
```